# Services in Android Studio

Tags: android, service

I am working with services in Android Studio, it is a little App with two Buttons, start audio button and stop audio button, when I press start button, service begins and that service starts a mp3 song. When y close the app, the music stops and after the music starts again because the service starts in background. But it makes a little stop and song starts from the beginning, I want to know if I can close the app and continue the service without stop music?.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) on the method [onStartCommand](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand)

Comment: Yes I already tried with START_STICKY and START_NOT_STICKY. It didn't work.